# read data from ipfs in a solidity contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ipfs

Is there a way to read data from an IPFS address inside of a solidity contract?

I found questions about writing to ipfs, which isn't what solidity should be used for, but I can't find anything regarding reading.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data you're refering to here. For example ERC721 has a token URI option that stores the URI of the IPFS link where your NFT attributes and details are stored and if it is in openSea standard format. Opensea will read it to display there as well. For others, you have chainlink that can fetch the data for you but even they have their standards that help them fetch the data for specific purpose distributed amongst their varioud API's.